# Select all active indent keyboard shortcut in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for selecting everyting in the current active indent in VS Code, that could be useful for selecting a React or html component for example.

Basically, I'd like to select everything that has an indentation of at least same or more as the highlighted indent guide as shown below in two pictures. This guide line/stripe can be enabled through `editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide`

When cursor and highlighted indent guide are like below:

[image: Highlighted active indent guide]

keyboard shortcut should select this:

[image: After selecting]

I often find myself trying to select an entire React component which could be 10 lines sometimes, so it'd be pretty handy to have such shortcut. If there is any extension which would let me do it, it could work too.

If it doesn't exist at all, I'll send a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` command: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>.  You just have to hit it twice to do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, smartSelect does not do what I want at all. Try to select only component2 or component1 in the example.